# Direct Parquet source (Spark Engine) vs "SQL-Select external table (pointing to that Parquet) on Serverless SQL" source (SQL Engine)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, pipeline, parquet, external-tables

In a pipeline, in a Data Flow, I can use as a source:

1. the parquet file
2. or a sql query to an external table on the serverless sql, that points to the parquet file

Assuming that the sink is another parquet file, which of the two options is better?
**is the first option more direct?**

On the other hand,
what if I'd put a "filter sequence" between the "parquet source" and sink:
**is that better** than filtering with "where" clause in the "serverless sql query source" (the second option)?

that is :

"parquet source > filter > parquet sink"

is better than "select...WHERE... source > parquet sink" ???

**EDIT** : the real question behind is about Spark Engine vs SQL Engine

Answer (score 0):

Using the Parquet file as a source gives you some flexibility, you can use parameters to query directly one file, or query only the files created since the last load.
Also, if you need to change something on the source, you don't have to go and change the external table too.

However, in your second question, It's usually much better to filter the data in advance, instead of bringing all the data to data flow and filtering it there.

The best option would be, if applicable, to filter the files in a data flow source by using the files create date or reading specific folder.

Comment: thanks, I edited the question. What I want to know is, in both options, if Spark Engine performs better than SQL Engine

Comment: @Hernán , It's hard to predict what will give you the best performance. You will have to try both options and measure performance time and costs to compare.

Comment: Ok, there is no a best choice a priori. I thought direct parquet was better, thought SQL introduced some extra cost